# Cannot change part of a merged cell Error Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to append the data from all worksheets, however in my code i am able to append from 1st sheet only. The code which i have written will converts all html file to excel in 1 workbooks and then i would like to append in 1 sheet. while executing my code an error is prompting "Cannot change part of a merged cell"
Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub Demo()


'Convert HTML to EXCEL and Gathers a file
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
Dim strOpenFiles As String
Set WorkbookDestination = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
If intChoice <> 0 Then

    For i = 1 To Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
        ).SelectedItems.count
        strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen _
        ).SelectedItems(i)

            Set WorkbookSource = Workbooks.Open(strPath)
            Set WorksheetSource = WorkbookSource.Worksheets(1)
            WorksheetSource.Copy After:=WorkbookDestination.Worksheets(WorkbookDestination.Worksheets.count)
            Rows("1:2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
            WorkbookSource.Close
    Next i
        'Merges the Sheet
                        For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
                            a = ActiveSheet.Rows.count
                            Sheets(i).Activate

                           ' ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select
                            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
                            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
                            ActiveSheet.Paste
                        Next i


End If
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid merged cells. They make life harder. Go through all the worksheets and unmerge merged cells before you run the macro.

Instead of merged cells use "Center across selection" in the Alignment tab of the Format dialog. For vertically merged cells just don't merge them. Use cell borders to determine cells that belong together.

That way, every cell, every row, every column can be selected and addressed individually without any errors or problems.

Comment: thanks teylyn, but the macro starts from converting html file to excel so inbetween how can i change it manually ?

Comment: Before processing the file, select all cells and unmerge. VBA can do that.

Comment: ya i got it. one more help i am not able to append the data it just override it.

Comment: I don't  understand. Use punctuation.